# D3 stack() vs nested objects

Tags: d3.js

I'm running into an issue when trying to implement a normalized stacked bar chart using D3v4.
The problem occurs due to my data format which contains nested object arrays populated dynamically on the server side.

```
var data = [{x:"data1", y:[{name:"red", value:10}, {name:"green", value:20}]},
            {x:"data2", y:[{name:"red", value:30}, {name:"green", value:5}]}];
```

Calling `d3.stack()` on this will not work since d3 doesn't know how to traverse into the object array `y`. (https://jsfiddle.net/xv1qgqjg/)
Is there any way to tell `d3.stack()` where to find the relevant data similar to the `.data(function(d){ return d.y; })` used elsewhere?

Comment: You can copy your y items into a new object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible. According to the documentation regarding *stack(data[, arguments…])*,

> Any additional arguments are arbitrary; they are simply propagated to accessors along with the this object.

Thus, you'll have to change your data, creating an array which you can pass to `d3.stack()`, such as this:

```
[{red:10,green:20},
{red:30,green:5}]
```

Given the data array in your question, there are several ways for creating the above-mentioned array. Here is my solution (the new array is called `newData`):

```
newData = [];

data.forEach(d => {
    var tempObj = {}
    d.y.forEach(e => {
        tempObj[e.name] = e.value;
    })
    newData.push(tempObj);
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [{x:"data1", y:[{name:"red", value:10}, {name:"green", value:20}]},
            {x:"data2", y:[{name:"red", value:30}, {name:"green", value:5}]}];

newData = [];

data.forEach(d => {
    var tempObj = {}
    d.y.forEach(e => {
        tempObj[e.name] = e.value;
    })
    newData.push(tempObj);
});

var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(["red", "green"])
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand);

var series = stack(newData);
console.dir(series);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, seems I will have to implement some preprocessing to get the required data format.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it seems to be the case.